# How to set morris.js values from Rails controller

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, morris.js

I struggle with adding circle graph in my sport app.
Is it possible to set **morris.js** value to variable from my controller?
I have **@diet_calories** variable in controller and I want to display Carbs -> Protein -> Fat in **60% -> 20% -> 20%** relation. If I set value of carbs in script tag (**value: @diet_calories * 0.6**) it dosn't work.
Do you have some suggestions to fix that?

***application.html.erb :***

```
<script>
    new Morris.Donut({
         element: 'diet-circle',
         data: [
           { label: "Carbs", value: @diet_calories * 0.6 },
           { label: "Protein", value: @diet_calories * 0.2 },
           { label: "Fat", value: @diet_calories * 0.2 }
         ]
    });
</script>
```

***info_controller.rb :***

```
def diet
    if current_user.activity == "Sedentary"
        if current_user.goals == "Lose Weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 1.1) - 300).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Maintain Weight"
            @diet_calories = (@bmr * 1.1).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Add some weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 1.1) + 300).to_i
        end
    elsif current_user.activity == "Low"
        if current_user.goals == "Lose Weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 1.5) - 300).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Maintain Weight"
            @diet_calories = (@bmr * 1.5).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Add some weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 1.5) + 300).to_i
        end
    elsif current_user.activity == "Medium"
        if current_user.goals == "Lose Weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 1.7) - 300).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Maintain Weight"
            @diet_calories = (@bmr * 1.7).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Add some weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 1.7) + 300).to_i
        end
    elsif current_user.activity == "High"
        if current_user.goals == "Lose Weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 2.1) - 300).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Maintain Weight"
            @diet_calories = (@bmr * 2.1).to_i
        elsif current_user.goals == "Add some weight"
            @diet_calories = ((@bmr * 2.1) + 300).to_i
        end
    end
```

***diet.html.erb :***

```
<div id="diet-circle"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this, by making this change 
in your application.html.erb

```
<script>
     var diet_calories = <%= @diet_calories %>
     new Morris.Donut({
     element: 'diet-circle',
     data: [
       { label: "Carbs", value: diet_calories * 0.6 },
       { label: "Protein", value: diet_calories * 0.2 },
       { label: "Fat", value: diet_calories * 0.2 }
     ]
  });
</script>
```

To further understand passing of variable from rails to javascript, have a look at [this railscast.](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)

Comment: Great. Thank you for answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try with:

```
<script>
    new Morris.Donut({
         element: 'diet-circle',
         data: [
           { label: "Carbs", value: <%= @diet_calories %> * 0.6  },
           { label: "Protein", value: <%= @diet_calories %> * 0.2 },
           { label: "Fat", value: <%= @diet_calories %> * 0.2 }
         ]
    });
</script>
```

`.erb` stands for **Embedded RuBy**. 
In a `.erb` file to evaluate Ruby code (example use instance variables set in the controller) you need to use `<%= ruby code %>`

You can read an introduction to Erb templating [here](http://An%20Introduction%20to%20ERB%20Templating)

Comment: @SzymonRadosz glad to help you :)